# google tv emulator zip code field disabled

Tags: google-tv

I'm trying to run the [ChannelChanging example](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_demo_samples#ChannelChanging) on the googletv dev site and it's returning and empty channel list.   I went ahead and tried to configure the emulator video source in the emulator's video input settings but its now allowing me to type in a zip code.  The field appears to be disabled.  Has anyone experienced this problem? I'm running an x86 emulator on a ubuntu 64 bit installation configured with kvm.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The current release of emulator does have some bugs but they are fixed in the upcoming release. There will be a new emulator release soon which will fix this and other issues.